# How to change a popup image based on item click

Tags: jquery

I am displaying two image (from database) using loop . it is showing well. on click of first image, it is opening the popup with correct image but when i am clicking on second button it is still showing the first image in popup.How can i change image respectively.
 Image and popup image are coming from the database. I inspect my code using developer tools, but still not able to change popup image.popup function is working properly opening and closing, but it is not changing the image based on item click.

This is my php blade for displaying image and popup.

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($product->images as $Image)
        <div class="col sm-12 col-md-6 mb-3 open">
            <img class="mb-2 get-started" src="{{ $Image->url }}"/> 
        </div>          
        <div id="popup-container">
            <div id="popup-window">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>  
                <a href="#" class="your-class"></a>
            <div class="row">
            <img src="{{ $Image->pop_url }}"> 
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

My Jquery

```
    $('.get-started').on('click', function() {
       var $sidenav, $this;
       $this = $(this);
       $sidenav = $('#popup-container');
       if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
          $this.removeClass('active');
          return $sidenav.removeClass('active');
       } else {
          $this.addClass('active');
          return $sidenav.addClass('active');
       }
    });
    $('.get-started').on('click', function() {
       var $sidenav, $this;
       $this = $(this);
       $sidenav = $('#popup-container');
       if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
          $this.removeClass('open');
          return $sidenav.removeClass('open');
       } else {
          $this.addClass('open');
          return $sidenav.addClass('open');

       }
    });
    $('#popup-container').find('.close').on('click', function() {
       $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
       $('.get-started').removeClass('open')
       return $('#popup-container').removeClass('open');
       return $('.get-started').removeClass('open');
    });

    $('#show').on('click', function() {
       $('.center').show();
       $(this).hide();
    });

    $('#close').on('click', function() {
       $('.center').hide();
       $('#show').show();
    })
```

Comment: You have to play with id, Using id you can do it

Comment: Try to avoid using `id` in elements because it's unique, try with `class` in place of `id` `popup-container`.